# What is the relationship between vert.x, sockJS, and websockets?

Tags: websocket, vert.x, sockjs

I'm extremely new to all of this, but from my understanding, websockets allow for a bidirectional transfer of information between browsers. Vert.x is a library that allows for asynchronous I/O. And sockJS is a JavaScript library that attempts to use websockets for communication, and provides fallback options otherwise.

But if I'm writing something in Java using vert.x, I don't quite understand how the pieces fit together. Does vert.x actually support websockets? Or do I need a combination of vert.x and sockJS to make that happen?

Comment: Have you read documentation? It has information about working with WebSockets and SockS: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/ and http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/

Comment: If you want to see an example with some details, check this out: https://itnext.io/web-sockets-with-vert-x-and-sockjs-1f0710264eea

Answer (score 1):

HTTP(s) is a stateless protocol, which means that once its job is done it will be idle till the next job is given.

So lets take an example of chat application, assume A is chatting with B using HTTP protocol. B has sent a message which is in server, now until A refreshes the browser, B's message will not appear. That's stateless behavior.

Coming to sockets, which is not stateless. Sockets use ws protocol which is always connected to the server. Taking the same example, now if B sends a message, A's socket will fetch and display to the browser, without the need to refresh. That's how sockets work.

To serve a webpage you need an http server. Similarly to use sockets, sockets server is needed. Which is provided by Vert.x. So Vert.x will start socket server, your browser will listen to that server using clientside sock.js file.